# MUI installation doesn't work with React 16

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have react v16.1.3 and I am unable to install these two packages

- @mui/material
- @mui/x-data-grid

I have tried lowest to highest all versions but it is not working.
On internet I found two solution

- Via legacy props
- Via --force

But that is not my solution because this works locally but on my dev environment it agains throws same error in pipelines

Comment: The current versions of MUI require at least v17 of React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the version of react-scripts to latest one and it resolved the issue